# CS1023 Embedded statement cannot be a declaration or labeled statement

Tags: c#

I have a programm which works correctly. This a correct code.

```
public static double Smth(int x, int y, double[,] original, int lengthX, int lengthY)
        {
            var pixelsFields = new List<double>();
            double median;
            for (int areasX = -1; areasX < 2; areasX++)
                for (int areasY = -1; areasY < 2; areasY++)
                    if ((x + areasX > -1) && (y + areasY > -1) && (x + areasX < lengthX) && (y + areasY < lengthY))
                        pixelsFields.Add(original[x + areasX, y + areasY]);
```

However, I would like to improve my code. Expressions "x + areasX" and "y + areasY" repeat often, so I decided to create two variables. Unfortunately, I have an error on new variables: "error CS1023: Embedded statement cannot be a declaration or labeled statement".

```
public static double Smth(int x, int y, double[,] original, int lengthX, int lengthY)
            {
                var pixelsFields = new List<double>();
                double median;
                for (int areasX = -1; areasX < 2; areasX++)
                    for (int areasY = -1; areasY < 2; areasY++)
                        var diffX = x + areasX;
                        var diffY = y + areasY;
                        if ((diffX > -1) && (diffY > -1) && (diffX < lengthX) && (diffY < lengthY))
                            pixelsFields.Add(original[diffX, diffY]);
```

Could you help me and correct?

Comment: try declaring the var diffX and diffY where you delcare the pxelsFields

Comment: You need braces to express the scope of your for loops. It's not recommended practice to not use braces to express scope. It can get confusing and lead to these kind of bugs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C#, constructs like `if` and `for` capture the next statement only, regardless of whitespace. When you write:

```
var pixelsFields = new List<double>();
double median;
for (int areasX = -1; areasX < 2; areasX++)
    for (int areasY = -1; areasY < 2; areasY++)
        var diffX = x + areasX;
        var diffY = y + areasY;
        if ((diffX > -1) && (diffY > -1) && (diffX < lengthX) && (diffY < lengthY))
            pixelsFields.Add(original[diffX, diffY]);
```

the language interprets this as the following, (where we pretend that whitespace/indent **is** significant):

```
var pixelsFields = new List<double>();
double median;
for (int areasX = -1; areasX < 2; areasX++)
    for (int areasY = -1; areasY < 2; areasY++)
        var diffX = x + areasX;
var diffY = y + areasY;
if ((diffX > -1) && (diffY > -1) && (diffX < lengthX) && (diffY < lengthY))
    pixelsFields.Add(original[diffX, diffY]);
```

As the other answers have mentioned, the solution is to use braces `{` and `}`, e.g.:

```
var pixelsFields = new List<double>();
double median;
for (int areasX = -1; areasX < 2; areasX++)
{
    for (int areasY = -1; areasY < 2; areasY++)
    {
        var diffX = x + areasX;
        var diffY = y + areasY;
        if ((diffX > -1) && (diffY > -1) && (diffX < lengthX) && (diffY < lengthY))
        {
            pixelsFields.Add(original[diffX, diffY]);
        }
    }
}
```

Most style guides require you to use braces like this. If you don't, you could accidentally cause a statement that was in a loop to no longer be in that loop when you add another statement, as you can see in this case.

As for the error you're getting specifically, your inner `for` loop has just one statement: `var diffX = x + areasX;`. [CS1023](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs1023) arises because this single statement is a variable declaration. The language prohibits this, probably to avoid the problem I mentioned, and possibly because it's syntactically ambiguous whether such a variable's scope would end immediately, or to the next `}`.

Answer (score 2):

You have missing bracets after for loop

```
 public static double Smth(int x, int y, double[,] original, int lengthX, int lengthY)
   {
        var pixelsFields = new List<double>();
        double median;
        for (int areasX = -1; areasX < 2; areasX++)
            for (int areasY = -1; areasY < 2; areasY++)
            {
                var diffX = x + areasX;
                var diffY = y + areasY;
                if ((diffX > -1) && (diffY > -1) && (diffX < lengthX) && (diffY < lengthY))
                    pixelsFields.Add(original[diffX, diffY]);
            }
```